How to set Recharts custom tooltip additional argument (React, typescript)
I'm trying to use recharts custom tooltip with additional argument.
But when I change from js to typescript, I got an error.
define function
import { TooltipProps } from "recharts";
import { ValueType,
  NameType,
} from "recharts/types/component/DefaultTooltipContent";

const CustomTooltip = (
    { active, payload, label }: TooltipProps<ValueType, NameType>,
    { StackedBarChartLabel }: { StackedBarChartLabel: BarChartShareLabelState }
  ) => {
    if (active && payload && payload.length) {
      return (
        <div style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}>
          <p>{label}</p>
          {payload.map((pld: any) => (
            <p key={pld.dataKey}>
              {pld.dataKey}:{StackedBarChartLabel[`${label}`][`${pld.dataKey}`]}
            </p>
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    }
    return null;
  };


call function
<Tooltip
  content={(props) => (
    <CustomTooltip
       {...(props as TooltipProps<ValueType, NameType>)}
       StackedBarChartLabel={dataset.StackedBarChartLabel}
   />
   )}
/>

error message
Property 'StackedBarChartLabel' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props<ValueType, NameType> & { accessibilityLayer?: boolean; active?: boolean; includeHidden?: boolean; ... 17 more ...; wrapperStyle?: CSSProperties; }'.

I excepted that component doesn't recognize TooltipProps type.
Thanks

I found a solution.
Overloading types and defining functions.
type MyTooltipState = TooltipProps<ValueType, NameType> & {
     StackedBarChartLabel: BarChartShareLabelState;};

const CustomTooltip = ({
    active,
    payload,
    label,
    StackedBarChartLabel,
}: MyTooltipState) => {
  if (active && payload && payload.length) {
    return (
      <div style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}>
        <p>{label}</p>
          {payload.map((pld: any) => (
        <p key={pld.dataKey}>
          {pld.dataKey}:{StackedBarChartLabel[`${label}`][`${pld.dataKey}`]}
        </p>
   ))}
</div>);}
return null;};

Call the function as follows.
<Tooltip
    content={(props) => (
    <CustomTooltip
       active={props.active}
       payload={props.payload}
       label={props.label}
    　 StackedBarChartLabel={dataset.StackedBarChartLabel}
    />)}
 />


you can also use code like this in ResponsiveContainer :
<Tooltip content={<CustomTooltip />} />

you do not need to pass call function which you are being called.

Thanks. I want to add additional argument like  how to set?

Yeah, sure. You can add additional arguments, but in some cases, this causes more load on the canvas and gives errors, so it's better to use functions for arguments.

Thanks. As I am a beginner, could you be more specific?
I want to get the label information from the object and display it according to the state of TooltipProps.

You can use this prompt for the issue you're facing:
StackedBarChartLabel[label]?.[pld.dataKey];
I think, you might be resolved the issue by following this.
